# Color.parseColor not working on some colors - Android

Tags: android

I am using many colors in an android app. However some colors are parsed , on some others the app crashes. Error in logcat is illegal arguement :unknown color. Below is the code,
working colors are below,
I would like to know why color.parseColor doesn't work for silver, lime , navy
Thanks

```
            if(selected_color == "WHITE"){
              selected_color = "#FFFFFF";


            }
           if( selected_color == "RED"){

                 selected_color = "#FF0000";

            }
           if(selected_color == "YELLOW"){
                selected_color = "#FFFF00";


            }
            if(selected_color == "BLACK"){
                selected_color = "#000000";


            }
```

// not working colors are below

```
 if(selected_color== "SILVER") {
                selected_color = "#C0C0C0";

            }


            if(selected_color == "LIME"){
                selected_color = "#00FF00";


            }

            if(selected_color == "NAVY"){
               selected_color = "#000080";

            }



Paint myPaint = new Paint();


myPaint.setColor(Color.parseColor(selected_color);
```

Comment: Post your logcat please

Comment: Illegal arguement exception: unknown color

Comment: Your string compares are all wonky, don't use `==` use `.equals()`. My guess is the compares aren't working and you are giving the color name straight to the `parseColor()` function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are making wrong String comparison, use `.equals()` method instead of `==` operator for String comparison.

do it  like,

```
selected_color.equals("NAVY")
```

just inspect value of `selected_color` 
before code line,

```
myPaint.setColor(Color.parseColor(selected_color);
```